# Template specialization for static function when compiling with g++

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Why does the following code not work when compiling with:

```
$ g++ temp_main.cpp temp_spec.cpp
/tmp/ccirjc3Y.o:temp_spec.cpp:(.text+0x100): multiple definition of `my::say()'
/tmp/ccSo7IVO.o:temp_main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2myILi0EE3sayEv[my::say()]+0x0):
first defined here collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm trying to have specialization of static function only when using
paramteter 0.

**temp_gen.h:**

```
#ifndef temp_gen_h
#define temp_gen_h

#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct my
{
   static void say();
};

template<int N>
void my<N>::say()
{
   std::cout << "generic " << N << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

**temp_spec.h:**

```
#ifndef temp_spec_h
#define temp_spec_h

#include <iostream>

#include "temp_gen.h"

template<>
void my<0>::say()
{
   std::cout << "specialized " << 0 << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

**temp_spec.cpp:**

```
#include "temp_spec.h"
```

**temp_main.cpp:**

```
#include "temp_gen.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   my<0>::say();  //should say "specialized 0"
   my<1>::say();  //should say "generic 0"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within your `main.cpp`, you did not specialize the template class, this is because you don't include the `temp_spec.h`.

As Vaughn Cato pointed out (see comments), you should move the *definition* of the specialized method (which is no template method anymore), to `temp_spec.cpp`.

I think (but I'm not an expert at this) you should always **put specialization directly below the generic template** (in the same header file), because whenever you include this, you also want the specialized ones to be defined, otherwise you will be confused when such errors happen. You can, however, just include the `temp_spec.h` at the bottom of `temp_gen.h`.

<del>Also, you don't need the .cpp files for the template headers, as there will never be any code to be compiled separately (template classes are always compiled at the other .cpp file which uses it, and I think duplicates will be removed when linking, causing **trouble at link time** again when in one case you *did not* specialize it, one time you *did*)</del> [This paragraph only applies to the generic template class, not to (fully) specialized classes, as they *require* some code in their own compilation unit, see comments and the edit above.]

Comment: The reason why is that the compiler instantiates the template in the object file in which it is used; the linker merely goes through and merges the duplicate instances. Here, the linker is confused because an instance of `my<0>::say()` shows up in two different object files *and they do not match.*

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Oh, I just added this before I read your comment ;)

Comment: Not just template classes, but anything templated. And the rule is that the specializations only need to be after the template *declaration*. Thus you could define `template<> void my<0>::say() {...}` before `template<int N> void my<N>::say() {...}` so long as both are after `template<int N> class my {... static void say(); ...}`

Comment: template<> means an explicit specialization.  Explicit specializations are not templates, and they should not be in header files.

Comment: @VaughnCato But where should we put it instead? I thought that the code where we use the method (here in main) it already had to be specialized *in the same compilation unit*. Or it is resolved (replaced) at link time?

Comment: @leemes: It needs to be declared in the header and defined in the cpp, like a regular function.

Comment: @VaughnCato Ah okay. I thought as we directly define template methods (and methods of template classes) in headers, this also applies for specialized (and because of this non-template) methods. Thanks for pointing this out. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: @leemes: That applies to partial specializations, which are still templates, but explicit specializations are not templates, despite the syntax.  It is a common source of confusion.

Comment: @VaughnCato So my last paragraph doesn't apply here to the `temp_spec.cpp`, but it *would* apply if we *did not* define the methods in a separate compilation unit, like we would if we *partly* specialized it, right?

Comment: @leemes: It is a good idea to put the class template and the related specializations together.  Some specializations may not be related though.  For example with traits-style templates.  It's just that if you do put a related specialization in the same header file, and it is an explicit specialization, then only the declaration should be in the header file, or it should be inline.

Comment: @VaughnCato To recap, you're saying I should declare the specialized function like so: `template<> void my<0>::say();` inside the **temp_gen.h** and implement it **temp_spec.cpp**? That is because that is explicit template specialization, because N is completely defined.
If it wasn't explicit spec, like making specialization for typename N instead of int N, then it should be in temp_gen.h?

Comment: @VaughnCato To recap, you're saying I should declare the specialized function like so: `template<> void my<0>::say();` inside the **temp_gen.h** and implement it **temp_spec.cpp**? That is because that is explicit template specialization, because N is completely defined. If it wasn't explicit spec, like making specialization for typename N (base template is typename N, partial spec is N*) then it should be in **temp_gen.h**?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that since your template specialization's implementation is in the header you'll need to mark it `inline` so the compiler/linker know you're allowed to violate the one definition rule.

Comment: I put inline in front of say implementations but the program when invoked outputs generic 0, generic 1, and it should be specialized 0, generic 1

Comment: I thought one-definition-rule is already allowed to be violated when defining some template stuff? Because it needs to be defined for all compilations separately (for the template definition is not known for which types `T` it has to be compiled before we really use it for a specific type), and merged on link time. This is at least how I understand how it works...

Comment: @omittones: Since you aren't including temp_spec.h in temp_main.cpp, the specialization is not visible, so the main function uses the generic definition instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using the n3337 version of the Standard (emphasis mine):

> **14.7.3 Explicit specialization [temp.expl.spec]**
>
> **6/** If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, **in every translation unit** in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

Because in `main` the specialization of `my<0>::say` is not visible, implicit instantiation occurs and you end up in the case above: *no diagnostic required* (from the compiler).

Note that a specialization may only be declared after its generic counterpart has been declared.